# Spring PreAuthorize SecurityContext not populated on parallelStream

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, java-stream

I have 2 methods, each in a separate Spring Bean:

CarService:

```java
PreAuthorize("someCheck(#carId)")
public List<Color> getCarColors(String carId) {
  return this.getCar(carId).getColors().parallelStream()
    .map(ColorService::getColor)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

ColorService:

```java
PreAuthorize ("someOtherCeck(#colorId)")
public Color getColor(String colorId) {
  return this.colorRepository.findById(colorId);
}
```

These methods are for the sake of example, just the easiest way to easily explain the problem.

The first check (`someCheck`), passes fine, but the second check (`someOtherCheck`) throws an exception:

> An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext

I know the `parallelStream` uses multiple threads, so I added the following line to my `application.properties`:

```
spring.security.strategy=MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL
```

But that does not fix the issue, the SecurityContext is not populated in a new thread and the second PreAuthorize complains about no Authentication is found in the SecurityContext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using `parallelStream`, you're using threads from Java's native thread pool. You need to use Spring's `@Async` in order to activate `MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL`.

To use `@Async`, you need to first set up a thread pool.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncExecutionConfiguration extends AsyncConfigurerSupport {
   @PostConstruct
   protected void init() { 
       SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL);
   }

    @Override
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        // Copy the current RequestContext to each and every new @Async task
        executor.setCorePoolSize(standardPoolConfigs.getCorePoolSize());
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(standardPoolConfigs.getMaxPoolSize());
        executor.setQueueCapacity(standardPoolConfigs.getQueueCapacity());
        executor.setThreadPriority(standardPoolConfigs.getThreadPriority());
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("async-thread-");
        executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
        executor.initialize();

        return executor;
    }
}
```

Then you can use `CompletableFuture` to capture the result.

```
@Async
public CompletableFuture<Color> getColor(String colorId) {
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(this.colorRepository.findById(colorId));
}
```

Then you can stream this way.

```
@Service
public class ColorService {
    @Resource
    private ColorService self;

    public Collection<Color> getCarColors(String carId) {
        Queue<Color> colors = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

        this.getCar(carId)
            .getColors()
            .stream()
            .map(colorId -> self.getColor(colorId)
                                .thenAccept(colors::add))
            .collect(CompletableFutures.joinList());

        return colors;
    }
}
```

Add this to your `pom.xml`.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
  <artifactId>completable-futures</artifactId>
  <version>${completable-futures.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Instead of doing `public CompletableFuture<Color> getColor(String colorId)`, you can actually still use `public Color getColor(String colorId)` even without `@Async` on top of it. However, you need to change the caller to use `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync` instead. Then you can pass the thread pool you created in `@Configuration` to `supplyAsync`. I'll let you explore that path ;)

Comment: As I stated, the code is just an example to illustrate the problem. You don't have to worry about this code ever being used for real. Could you point me to some documentation that describes how to combine the parallelStream, @Async and MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL?

Comment: Ah sry, I didn't see that part :)). I skimmed through your post. Updated my post with some code.

Comment: Thanks! But so there is no out-of-the box support to actually use parallelStream with PreAuthorize annotations?

Comment: @Titulum: not that I'm aware of. Most of the times, Spring stuff only works with Spring stuff :)